# how to get selectd code and selected name value from spinner in android

Tags: android

this is my Asynk task am getting data from server and calling in Oncreate method

```
   class download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            String result;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPreExecute();

                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RDistributor.this);
                pDialog.setTitle("CheckUser Connection");
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    result = JSONfunctions2.getJSONfromURL(URL + "?spokecode="
                            + "GUJAHM270");
                    _jarray1 = new JSONArray(result);

                    stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
                    // stringArray.add("Select Role");
                    for (int i = 0; i <= _jarray1.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject _obj = _jarray1.getJSONObject(i);
                        SpokeCode = _obj.getString("SpokeCode").toString();
                        DistributerCode = _obj.getString("DistributerCode")
                                .toString();
                        DistributerName = _obj.getString("DistributerName")
                                .toString();

                        stringArray.add(DistributerName);

                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (_jarray1.length() == 0) {
                    showpopup("All Distributers had already been registered!");

                } else {
                    dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(RDistributor.this,
                            R.layout.spinner_item, stringArray);
                    // ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new
                    // ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_item,
                    // stringArray);
                    dataAdapter
                            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    // set the ArrayAdapter to the spinner
                    rolespinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                }
                pDialog.dismiss();
                super.onPostExecute(result);

            }
        }
```

this is itemselected of spinner and getting value .

```
rolespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                DistributerName=rolespinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                Toast.makeText(RDistributor.this, DistributerName, 10000).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

    }
```

i am printing data distributerName in Spinner which is coming from server also distributerCode and spoke code coming from server i want when i select distributor name corresponding i get value of distributor code and spoke code selection of ditributorname from drop down please suggest me how i will achieve this .i am facing issue to get this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare :

```
 HashMap<String, String> spinnerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

for (int i = 0; i <= _jarray1.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject _obj = _jarray1.getJSONObject(i);
                    SpokeCode = _obj.getString("SpokeCode").toString();
                    DistributerCode = _obj.getString("DistributerCode")
                            .toString();
                    DistributerName = _obj.getString("DistributerName")
                            .toString();

                    spinnerMap.put(DistributerName, DistributerCode);
                    stringArray.add(DistributerName);

                }
```

and spinner item-select Method update this :

rolespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
            int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String to=  spinnerMap.get(rolespinner.getSelectedItem());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
            to, 10000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

enjoy!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to wrap a object for storing these property.

```
 public class Model {
   public String spokeCode;
   public String DistributerCode;
   .......
 }

 ArrayList<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
 list.add(model);
 list.add(model);//
 // and so on
 //do search
 DistributerName=rolespinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
 Model searchModel;
 for (Model m : list) {
    if (m.distributerName.equals(DistributerName)) {
         searchModel = m;
         break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: list.add(model); will set the value of all ditributor code and spkoe code?

Comment: and also i have to Print ditributor name in drop on that basis i have get corresponding value os dirtirbutor code and spoke code i a getting those vlaue in asynk taske